# Communicate opened tab with HTML5 solutions

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage

Here is what i need: I have an index.html opened in my browser. I open a new window, for example, caller.html. When the caller.html loads in, it sends a message to the index.html.

How can i do this with html5? I thinking about Sharedworkers or Postmessage, but i didn't find a demo or sample code that i can easily implement to this feature.

I don't need crossbrowser and fallback solution.

Answer (score 0):

MDN has good documentation and an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: This is not really what i am looking for. Its only works, if the caller.html is a child of the index.html file (iframe, popup window)